# Facebook Graph Request is returning name but not email

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the graph api to return my name and email from a Facebook login. This is the code I use - name comes back fine, but email is nil:

```
func getUserInfo() {
    let params = ["fields" : "email, name"]
    let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
    graphRequest.start {
        (urlResponse, requestResult) in

        switch requestResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print("error in graph request:", error)
            break
        case .success(let graphResponse):
            if let responseDictionary = graphResponse.dictionaryValue {
                print(responseDictionary)

                if let name = responseDictionary["name"] {
                    self.nameLabel.text = "Logged in as: \n\(name)"
                }

                if let email = responseDictionary["email"] {
                    self.emailLabel.text = "Your email is: \n\(email)"
                } else {
                    self.emailLabel.text = "Your email is: "
                }
                print(responseDictionary["name"])
                print(responseDictionary["email"])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what prints to my console:

```
["id": 1653899307960705, "name": *my name removed for privacy*]
Optional(*my name removed for privacy*)
nil
```

I'm not sure if my code is wrong or it's just a bug - I specify both email and name as my parameters, but as you can see only the name comes back. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you ask the user for email permission?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely correct, there few possibilities that facebook graph API not providing email:

1. Registered user has submitted its email but not validated
2. User has set email (visibility) as private/limited access to friends only (not public)

Check account setting of an/your account (email is valid & validated as well as it is public)

Comment: You know, both of those are actually true.. the user in question is me and I'm pretty sure my email is friends only and not public (is anyone's?). And can't remember verifying my email anytime is the recent past either. If that's what it is, it's good to know it's not my code because this was driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you forgot to take email permission, so here I am sharing you code to take permission.

```
func fbLoginInitiate()
    {
        let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email","user_friends"], handler: {(result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                // Process error
                self.removeFbData()
            } else if result.isCancelled {
                // User Cancellation
                self.removeFbData()
            } else {
                //Success                
                if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email") && result.grantedPermissions.contains("public_profile") && result.grantedPermissions.contains("user_friends"){
                    //Here you need to call your function for graphRequest 
                    self.getUserInfo()
                } else {
                    //Handle error
                }
            }
        })
    }
func removeFbData()
    {
        //Remove FB Data
        let fbManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbManager.logOut()
        FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(nil)
    }
```